# What is this Klingon Santa saying?

Tags: star-trek, translation, klingon-language

I just received this by e-mail:

[image: Klingon Santa and his bird OF sleigh]

Can anyone fluent in Klingon translate what this Klingon Santa is saying?

Comment: Ah, that's the *original* Santa Clause, not the human rip-off. Good stuff!

Comment: Is that an elf hanging off the back of the "sleigh" or a Vulcan?

Comment: @bitmask: [Correct](http://www.thepoke.co.uk/2015/12/16/christmas-trivia-saint-nicholas-klingon/)!

Answer (score 52, accepted):

"May y'all enjoy Christmas and may y'all enjoy the new year."

QISmaS = Not a canonical tlhIngan Hol word, but a phonetic approximation of "Christmas".

bo- = Pronomial prefix; indicates that the subject of the verb is second-person plural and the object is third-person. "Y'all do something to him/her/it/them"
tIv = enjoy (verb)
-jaj = Verb suffix; indicates a wish on the speaker's part (similar to the jussive mood). "May it be so."

'ej = and (joining sentences)

DIS = year

chu' = be new

Edit: Also, the [pIqaD text](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klingon_alphabets#KLI_pIqaD) on his sleigh appears to say Sannta. That consonant cluster in the middle isn't really allowed in traditional tlhIngan Hol, but I think the Empire will forgive the artist; after all, it is *QISmaS* ;)

Indeed, big kudos to the artist for doing their research; most people take a lot of shortcuts when writing "Klingon", and that's quite understandable, but whenever somebody does get it right, it's a real treat for those of us in the Klingon-speaking community :)

Comment: bIpaw 'e' laj staqxchg tuq

Comment: maj! Daqvam vItu'pu'mo' jIbel!

Comment: Wait... a Klingon Santa from the deep south?

Answer (score 19):

According to [omniglot.com](http://www.omniglot.com/language/phrases/christmas.htm) it means:

**Merry Christmas and Happy New Year!**

Comment: *botlvjaj* appear 2 times in the bubble, should end it be "Merry Christmas and Merry New Year." or "Happy Christmas and Happy New Year." ?

Comment: Well, that's how a rather literal-minded machine would translate it.  A good translator would take the surrounding culture of the target language into account, hence the different and culturally expected wording.

Comment: And in this case it is even more difficult to translate, because I doubt that Klingons have a word for "merry".

Comment: Indeed, Klingons are not known to be [merry men](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K1Y5KsEptTY)